# Find out if geolocation.getCurrentPosition has been disabled

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Is there some simple setting to check if the user as disabled the GPS for your site, or do you have to use `geolocation.getCurrentPosition` and use the error callback?

Answer (score 0):

Besides the feature detection - `if ("geolocation" in navigator) {` - whether the user has granted you permission to use location services can only be determined by expressing your interest in the service first, either by using `getCurrentPosition()` or `watchPosition()` and passing in your error handler.